# Is it reasonable to use a journaling FS on a filesystem image that is stored on a filsystem that already provides journaling?

Tags: filesystems, ext4, disk-image, ext2

I need a filesystem image to put 150k files there, so they should be easily relocatable, i.e. mounted as a folder, when in use, unmounted and copied somewhere when needed. Due to the large number of files I’m going to pack them in a separate filesystem image, and I’m not sure whether I would need journal for this.

On one side, the main filesystem on which that image will reside is an ext4 with `data=journal` and `barrier=1` set. On the other side, if the file still gets corrupted, would the internal journal of the image be of any help? In other words, should I go with `ext4` or `ext2` would be enough?

---

P.S. No, I’m not interested in archivemount, squashfs of any other filesystem, except for xfs, maybe, if the journal won’t appear to be needed and it’s faster than ext2.

Comment: Honestly, no idea, but I'd ask myself is it possible for corruption (logical or physical) to occur in the filesystem image independently of any corruption in the filesystem hosting it.  If yes, use ext4, if no, use ext2.  Or, is the overhead of ext4 enough to even worry about the question - just use ext4 for both.

Comment: by "copied somewhere else", do you mean a different mount-point on the same system, or copied to a different system and mounted there?

Comment: @cas the latter.

Comment: i won't suggest `btrfs` or `zfs` subvolumes then - to take advantage of `btrfs send/receive` or `zfs send/recv` the remote system would also have to be using the same fs.

Answer (score 1):

ext2 may be fine if the total size is small, otherwise fsck will take ages. But for large things you should dedicate a block device (LV) anyhow, not rely on file in filesystem containers. It's easy to lose such containers to both inner and outer filesystem corruption. If you don't actually write the files, and they can be compressed, squashfs may be another option.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion to use a separate volume, but you make it seem like filesystem corruption occurs frequently... It doesn't in my experience!

Comment: LV is not an option. Only a mountable filesystem image, with R/W capability. I explicitly mentioned that neither archivemount, not squashfs are of any interest.